# How much data can be stored in the QR code on a pass in Apple Wallet?

Tags: qr-code, wallet, passkit

I know that the data storage capacity of a QR code is related to pixel size and physical dimensions.

The problem is, I don't know if the "sub squares" of QR codes in Apple Wallet are dynamic (e.g you add more data, Apple shrinks the squares to store it) ... so, I have no idea what the max capacity is.

And, of course, Apple's documentation doesn't say.

Comment: How much data are you looking to store?  With the exception of the 3GS and early generation iPod Touches that run Passbook on iOS6, all other hardware has a minimum of 320dpi.  The issue is less about storage, than your scanner’s ability to read a dense barcode.  Your best bet is to test your particular use case.

Comment: Was hoping to store about 3000 characters, but -- to your point -- I'm not sure the resolution will support.